# Indexed multi-value params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form like

```
<input name="url[0]" type="text" />
<input name="url[1]" type="text" />
<input name="url[2]" type="text" />
```

I would like to be able to access these like:

```
params[:url].each do |url|
  # work
end
```

I know that if I remove the explicit index from the name, this will work, but I would prefer to keep the index in. Is this something supported by rails out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your block like so:

```
params[:url].each do |index, url|
  # work
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`params[:url]` will be an hash like this:

```
params[:url]
 => {'0' => 'url-1', '1' => 'url-2', '2' => 'url-3'}
```

So you have to iterate over the hash like this:

```
params[:url].each do |key, value|
 # work
end
```